# replacing fragment with another fragment with OnClick on a Listview

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
public class Fragment_01 extends ListFragment {

String string[]={"Contact 1","Contact 2","Contact 3","Contact 4","Contact 5"};



    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container ,Bundle saveInstanceState) {

        View myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_01, container, false);
        ListView listView= (ListView) myview.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        ArrayAdapter<String> array = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,string);
        listView.setAdapter(array);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            Fragment_03 f3 = new Fragment_03();
            ft.replace(R.id.linearLayout2, f3);
            ft.commit();




           }

        });
        return myview;
    }


        }
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Do not change a fragment inside another. Have a frame layout n the activity. On click of an item in the list view, send the event to the activity through an interface and in the activity replace the fragment. This is the right way of replacing fragments.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Fragment_03 f3 = new Fragment_03();
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager();
 fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
   .replace(R.id.content_frame, new Fragment_03())
   .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//I am using this code without listView and this is working fine then why the other is not working ??

public class Fragment_01 extends Fragment {



   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container ,Bundle saveInstanceState){

    View myview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_01,container,false);
       Button btn = (Button) myview.findViewById(R.id.button);
       btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {


               FragmentManager fm =getFragmentManager();
               FragmentTransaction ft =fm.beginTransaction();
               Fragment_03 f3 = new Fragment_03();
               ft.replace(R.id.linearLayout2,f3);
               ft.commit();
           }
       });
    return myview;

}

}
```